# How to Export Teradata table data to an ORC file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, export, teradata, orc

We are exploring different ways to export table data from Teradata to ORC file. Few ways was

1. fastexport - wont give option of ORC file
2. Using TPT EXPORT - didn't get proper ORC file format as output

Need suggestions on different ways to Export data into ORC file

Comment: I see you tagged Spark-SQL. For TPT, did you try TDCH-TPT interface writing to Hive/Hadoop instance and HadoopFileFormat='orcfile'?